# Rotate an image from centre though accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, openframeworks

I'm using an android tablet with openFrameworks. I would want to use the accelerometer in order to rotate an image based on the accelerometer data.

I'm using the below code to draw the image based on accelerometer data.

```
ofPushMatrix();
ofTranslate(ofGetWidth()/2, ofGetHeight()/2);
im.setAnchorPoint(normAccel.x*ofGetWidth()/2, normAccel.y*ofGetHeight()/2);
im.draw(-300,-300);
ofPopMatrix();
```

But I am not sure how to go about rotating the image. I am not sure if i could use getOrientation() or getMatrix() methods to rotate the image. Any guidance would be very grateful.

Comment: Not familiar with openFrameworks, but from the Android SensorManager  API you would want to pass the acceleration vector into getQuaternionFromVector(float[] Q, float[] rv) or getRotationMatrixFromVector(float[] R, float[] rotationVector) and then rotate your image by the result. getOrienation() and getMatrix() will give you world space and that probably isn't what you are going for.